# How can Eclipse find JDK in Linux?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I've installed Eclipse and jdk manually. My JAVA_HOME is set, and I am able to run the *java -version* and *javac -version* commands, but when I try to run Eclipse, it shows the following message:

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/home/$USER/development/eclipse/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH
```

How can I fix this?

Distro:

```
Ubuntu 12.0.4 64 bits.
```

Java:

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

$JAVA_HOME:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45
```

My $PATH contains the following:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Just add it to that directory...

Comment: thanks, but add what to which directory?

Comment: /home/$USER/development/eclipse/jre/bin/java

Comment: you mean add my jdk folder to /home/$USER/development/eclipse/jre/bin/java directory?

Comment: Eclipse-> Windows-> Java -> Installed JRE -> Search button

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If Eclipse isn't finding your JRE/JDK or finding the wrong version, add the following two lines to the begining of your eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm
[your-path-to-java-executable]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. I thought I could resolve this just setting the environment variables, I don't like to edit this kind of file, an application script, but util now your suggestion it was the only one that works.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for adding the all important instruction "to the begining of your eclipse.ini file:"

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution is to add your java bin path to your environment variable PATH in /etc/profile file.
Something like this

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

Go to the end of the file and add this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/jdk/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with the other solutions, so the following is what I did:

1) Open a terminal window

2) Enter the eclipse sub-directory
   `cd ~/eclipse`

3) Execute: `whereis java`

4) Pick a jdk path that also has the jre as a sub-directory
   I chose: `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java`
   which has a jre subdir: `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre`

5) Create a symbolic link in the `~/eclipse` sub-directory.
   The following is an example:
   `ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre jre`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your jre path within JDK installation home and copy the jre directory under eclipse installation.

Answer (score 0):

[Folder Structure after download eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzGhg.png)

1. open eclipse.ini
   add on top

   -vm

[your-$JAVA_HOME-path]

ex: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/bin

Answer (score 0):

-startup
...
openFile

-vm
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/

-vmargs
...

Comment: This lacks an explanation how this works and why it is supposed to help. It also is weirdly similar to existing answers. In order to avoid the (probably undeserved) impression that you are just trying to get reputation by copying upvoted answers it is hence necessary to explain how the minor visible differences achieve a noticably different or better result. Additional details do not improve usefulness of the answer if the difference they make is not explained.